# Xcode 9.2 Archive failed but show no error

Tags: xcode, archive

[image]

Project can successfully run on Devices and Simulators, and Provisioning Profile is available in other projects.
What can I do next ?

Answer (score 0):

As the warning shows, I found the 'XXLog' macro is suspicious, checked it and  found only defined in Debug

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define XXLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
#endif
```

So, successfully run it on device and simulators, but when archive it, 'XXLog' macro can not successfully be called.

Correct code

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define XXLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
#else
#define XXLog(...)
#endif
```

I have to say the XCode error display is not friendly, but strictly speaking, all warning should be found out and eliminated.